# Modal verb past tense must have and had to

Tags: grammar

Which is more appropiate:
He must have taken all his medication or He had to have taken all his medication ?
I know must is less used in the past tense to stop confusion.

Comment: Your second sentence is wrong. "He had to take all his medication". But the two have different connotation to my non native ears.

Answer (score 1):

"Must have" is an idiom. It is used to indicate an assumption.

> Frank isn't at home.  Hmmm.  He must have gone to visit his friend.

The person observes that Frank is not here, and *assumes* that he is visiting his friend.

If you need to express a past compulsion you would use phrases like "was not allowed..." or "had to" or "was required to".

> When I was young, I was not allowed to wear trousers. I had to wear a skirt.

So if you mean "I assume that he has taken his medicine" you would use "He must have taken..."  But otherwise you could say:

> John had to take his medicine at 9am each day.

There are plenty of alternatives that express similar ideas. For example

> If John didn't take his medicine, he would be in trouble.

Comment: **He had to have taken all his medication..** is possible in some contexts as in: **He had to have taken all his medication before he retired, according to the doctor's instructions.** Unlike **must have taken**, which assumes that it was taken, this means that he was required of him. However, **he had to take** works better unless he has died or disappeared or similar.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, it's more clear now.